# How to insert DATETIME & BOOLEAN values using MYSQLI parameter binding?

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, bindparam

**On submission, this is my code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['send_money'])) {
     $date = explode("/",date('d/m/Y/h/i/s'));
     list($day,$month,$year,$hour,$min,$sec) = $date;
     $transaction_id = 'GMT'. $year .'.'.$day.$month.'.'.$hour . $min.$sec;
     $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['amount']);
     $sender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sender']);
     $receiver = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['receiver']);
     $collected = FALSE; // Boolean data type in database
     $approved = FALSE; // Boolean data type in database
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_id, date_of_transaction, amount,sender, receiver, collected, approved) 
  VALUES(?,now(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sdssss", $transaction_id, $amount, $sender, $receiver $collected, $approved);  
$query = $stmt->execute();
if($query){
    array_push($errors, "<h4 class='text-success text-center'>Transaction completed successfully</h4><hr/>");
  }else{
    array_push($errors, "<h4 class='text-danger text-center'>Couldn't complete transaction</h4><hr/>");
  }
}
```

The query cannot send the data to the database and can you assist in;

- **Inserting DATETIME using MySQLi parameter binding**
- **Inserting BOOLEAN using MySQLi parameter binding**

Comment: Just like any other string. What's the problem now?

Comment: Warning! `$amount` should not be a float/double. Money should be stored using DECIMAL type and used as a string in PHP/mysqli

Comment: So l should parse them as a `string s` ??

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` should not be used with prepared statement. This will damage your data.

Comment: Send everything as string in mysqli.

Comment: Thank you, let me align with what you advised.

Comment: `$collected = FALSE` will be cast to an empty string, however. Just use whatever value you have defined as false in your scheme. If it is zero then use `'0'`